# PhoneGap/Cordova CanvasCamera Plugin not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I am running the app on ios 9.2 via PhoneGap Desktop.

I have just started out using PhoneGap and I am trying to build a simple app that allows you to take a picture and show it back to you. I have been able to do this using the cordova camera plugin that launches the camera app on the device. however I would like to implement the app that launches a full screen camera as soon as the device is ready, just like snapchat.

I have been trying to do this using the CanvasCamera Plugin by Donald Pae https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin

But still I have had NO success in getting the camera preview.

I have installed the plugin via npm using gitbash

I have added the plugin to the config.xml file

```
    <gap:plugin name="com.keith.cordova.plugin.canvascamera" version="1.0.1" />
```

This is the code that I am using to try and get a camera preview

HTML

```
    <canvas id="camera" width="352" height="288" style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
```

index.js
Inside the bind events function

```
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
          canvasMain = document.getElementById("camera");
          window.plugin.CanvasCamera.initialize(canvasMain);
          // define options
          var opt = {
              quality: 75,
              destinationType: CanvasCamera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
              encodingType: CanvasCamera.EncodingType.JPEG,
              saveToPhotoAlbum:true,
              correctOrientation:true,
              width:640,
              height:480
          };
          window.plugin.CanvasCamera.start(opt);
      });
```

I really appreciate your help.

thanks

Comment: iOS 9.2 is not yet supported. See Cordova blog.

Comment: are you able to work around with this? the plugin is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the app through simulator via connecting your phone to your PC using USB. Note that you need to create iOS platform in order to run it in your phone. 
I hope it will work with you